# Draw my downslashes

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

As a programmer, you've probably heard of forward slashes and backward slashes. But have you heard of downslashes? That's when you take a bunch of slashes, connect their ends and draw them going down.

For today's challenge, you must write a program or function that takes a string consisting purely of slashes, and outputs all of those slashes drawn downwards in a line connecting them. This will be a lot more clear if you see an example. Given the string `\\\//\/\\`, you should output:

```
\
 \
  \
  /
 /
 \
 /
 \
  \
```

Here are some clarifications:

- There must be one slash per line.
- The first line will have 0 leading spaces.
- For each pair of slashes:

  - If they are different from each other, they will be drawn in the same column. For example, `\/` will give:

    ```
    \
    /
    ```
  - If they are the same character, the lower one is in the direction *pointed* to, that is moving to the right for a backslash, and moving to the left for a forward slash. So `\\//` will give

    ```
    \
     \
     /
    /
    ```
- Each line may have extra trailing whitespace as long as this doesn't change the visual appearance of the output. Up to one trailing and leading newline is also acceptable. Extra leading spaces *are not permitted*!

In order to keep this simpler, you can assume that the string will never contain too many forward slashes. In other words, no prefix of the input will contain more forward slashes than backslashes, so an input like `\\////` or `//` will never be given. This also means that every input will start with a backslash.

If your input is taken as a string literal, you may escape the backslashes if this is necessary. You will also never need to handle an input that is empty, or contains characters other than a slash.

You may output by any [reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/31716).

As usual, this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so try to make the shortest solution possible, even if you pick a language where this is rather difficult. Bonus points for explaining any interesting techniques you used to take bytes off!

### Examples

```
#Input
\\\\\\\\\\\

#Output
\
 \
  \
   \
    \
     \
      \
       \
        \
         \
          \

#Input
\\\//\\/\//\\///

#Output
\
 \
  \
  /
 /
 \
  \
  /
  \
  /
 /
 \
  \
  /
 /
/


#Input
\/\/\/

#Output
\
/
\
/
\
/
```

Comment: The backslashes make for an annoying amount of escaping lol...

Comment: Is the [formfeed/backslash method of moving the cursor around given in my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142672/11259) permissible for this question?

Comment: Can we output a list of lines?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing That seems like a reasonable IO method to me

Comment: @totallyhuman try python’s raw string: `r"/\\////\\/\/\/\\\\//////\/"` needs no escaping for any of the slashes.

Answer (score 22):

## GNU Sed, 20

```
s|\\|&^L|g
s|/|^H/^L^H|g
```

Note that `^L` and `^H` are literal formfeed and backspace characters (0x12 and 0x8).

This answer works by moving the cursor around using backspace and formfeed characters.  The slashes/backslashes are not left-padded with spaces - Not sure of this disqualifies this answer.  This doesn't work in TIO, but it looks fine under common terminals such as `xterm` and `gnome-terminal`.

Recreate this sed script as follows:

```
base64 -d <<< c3xcXHwmDHxnCnN8L3wILwwIfGc= > downslash.sed
```

Run it as follows:

```
$ echo '\\\//\/\\' | sed -f downslash.sed
\ 
 \ 
  \ 
  /
 /
 \ 
 /
 \ 
  \ 

$
```

#### Explanation:

```
s|\\|&^L|g     # move cursor down after every "\"
s|/|^H/^L^H|g  # move cursor left before every "/", then after, down and left again
```

Answer (score 16):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 119 bytes

/// has no input commands, so input must be embedded in the program. For this one, the input string is simply appended, with no escaping needed.

```
/=/\/\///M/
|%%=N/%|||=C/BA=\/\\/\/C\\=C\\/CbC=B\A\=CfC=AB=/A/%Mxy=B/|z%N|x|y% %N%x|y%%% |fzN%M%b|zN|M|%
=|/AB\\=%/|=AC
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY0xCsQwDAT7vCLN1vsCFbJr@wVuErhwxXVuErN/d@RDSMsyMOq/o38/fU4aWwxZuAmwSkiyzOQWYLHcmsUyn9lS8yhXNk9GJ8r9WKIGqm492FGxEth1jYqCU6OqCJuJnsIEyjx08fNvX5ec8wU)
- [With `-d` option](https://tio.run/##HY0xCsMwEAR7v8LNlmFfcIWkWnqBmpjYJBDigFLYZt8e5RyOu2UZmGvPa7vPrXcaqw@ZOQiwQkiyxBjMwclSrebLNCWLNXhZkoVoDETedovUgaJNO0YUnAmMWo6CjElHURYGE0N0EygLrvOff/t5yd6/6/vzWF@tX24/) (program state shown in brackets before each command is run).

## How it works

- In the following, an input of `\\/\//` will be appended to the program for demonstration.
- `␤` is used to represent newlines in inline code.

### Abbreviations

The beginning `/=/\/\///M/␤|%%=N/%|||=C/BA=` of the program contains substitutions for golfing abbreviations.

- `=` expands to `//`, `M` to `␤|%%`, `N` to `%|||` and `C` to `BA`.
- After this the current program becomes

  ```
  /\/\\/\/BA\\//BA\\/BAbBA//B\A\//BAfBA//AB///A/%
  |%%xy//B/|z%%||||x|y% %%|||%x|y%%% |fz%|||%
  |%%%b|z%||||
  |%%|%
  //|/AB\\//%/|//ABA\\/\//
  ```

### Input recoding

The next stage transforms the appended input string into a more usable form. Since it consists entirely of ///'s two command characters, this takes some care to avoid mangling the base program.

- The first substantial substitution, `/\/\\/\/BA\\/`, replaces the string `/\` with `/BA\`.

  - The base program does not contain `/\` at this time, so this substitution doesn't affect it.
  - However, this splits up the appended input string into sequences of `\`s followed by sequences of `/`s, which together with the `ABA` at the end of the base program makes it possible to iterate through it with the following substitutions.
  - Including the `ABA` prefix before it, the example input string now becomes `ABA\\/BA\//`.
- The next substitution, `/BA\\/BAbBA/`, replaces `BA\` by `BAbBA`.

  - Because /// substitutions are repeated until they no longer match, this iterates through all the `\`s of the input string, which with prefix now becomes `ABAbBAbBA/BAbBA//`
- Similarly, `/B\A\//BAfBA/` changes `BA/` to `BAfBA`, iterating through the `/`s.

  - The escaping `\` in this substitution is needed since otherwise it would be mangled by the previous one.
  - The input has now turned into `ABAbBAbBAfBABAbBAfBAfBA`.
- Next `/AB//` removes some superfluous parts of the encoding, turning it into `AbBAbBAfBAbBAfBAfBA`.

  - This also removes an `AB` from the `/|/AB\\/` substitution later in the program, which was needed to protect it from the above `/\` manipulation.
  - At this point every `\` in the original input string has become `AbB`, and every `/` has become `AfB`. (`b` and `f` stand for backward and forward.) There's a stray `A` at the end.
- The next two substitutions replace all the `A`s and `B`s with program fragments to run in the final stage. In the replacement strings, `%`s and `|`s encode what will become `/`s and `\`s respectively. This has two benefits:

  - Unlike `/` and `\`, the `%`s and `|`s don't need escaping to be copied.
  - The replacement strings avoid containing the substring `/\`, which would otherwise have been mangled by the previous manipulations.
- After this, the substitution `/|/\\/` (formerly `/|/AB\\/`) now decodes the `|`s, after which the following `/%/|//` has become `/%/\//` and decodes the `%`s.

### Program structure at final stage

At this point, the base program has run all its substitutions, and all that remains is the program-encoding of the input string.

- Each input character has become a subprogram

  ```
  /
  \//xy*\z//\\\\x\y/ //\\\/x\y/// \fz/\\\/
  \///b\z/\\\\
  \//\/
  ```

  (trailing newline), where `*` represents either `f` for an original `/`, or `b` for an original `\`.
- There is also an incomplete substitution command `/␤\//xy` at the end of the program, which will have no effect except to provide a necessary `/` for the substitutions of the previous subprogram.

### Shared substring

Before the final iteration through the subprograms starts, there is a substring crossing the boundary after each character's subprogram of the form `\/␤/`.

- These substrings are used as a shared global state. All the remaining substitutions in the program will manipulate them identically and in parallel, such that at the end of each input character's subprogram its copy of this shared substring (except the final `/`, which anchors the substitutions) will be run to print the line for that character.
- The initial version of the substring represents printing a line containing just `/`, which is the right imaginary "previous line" to cause the first input character to be printed at the beginning of its line.
- In general, during the printing steps, the shared substring consists of a number of spaces, `\\` or `\/`, a newline, and a following `/`.

### Running a character subprogram

Several of the following substitutions contain extra `\`s inside to prevent them from being matched and mangled by each other (including other copies in other subprograms). Achieving this is also the reason why both of `x` and `y` are needed.

- The first substitution in a character subprogram, `/␤\//xyf\z/` or `/␤\//xyb\z/`, causes the `␤/` at the end of the shared substring to become `xyfz` or `xybz`, immediately following the `\/` or `\\`.
- The substitution `/\\\\x\y/ /` replaces `\\xy` by a space, and the substitution `/\\\/x\y//` replaces `\/xy` by nothing.

  - They apply when the previous input character printed was a `\` or `/`, respectively.
  - The shared substring now contains the appropriate number of spaces for printing a `\` next, followed by `fz` or `bz`.
- The substitution `/ \fz/\\\/␤\//` replaces `​ fz` by `\/␤/`, and `/b\z/\\\\␤\//` replaces `bz` by `\\␤/`.

  - They apply when the current input character is `/` or `\`, respectively.
  - The first one eats an extra space to place `/` correctly.

    - If this space is missing (i.e. input violating the prefix condition), the following substitutions get misinterpreted, printing a lot of junk and usually hitting a `///`, which is an infinite loop.
  - Each adds the correct command to print its own character, and reinstates the original `␤/` at the end of the shared substring.
- The character subprogram has now reached its copy of the shared substring, which is ready to print its line.

After the last character subprogram has run, what remains of the program is `/␤\//xy`. Since this is an incomplete substitution with missing final `/`, the program skips it and halts normally.

Comment: The right language for the job! Lol

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> <s>57</s> 53 bytes

<sup>-3 bytes (and a bug fix) thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista</sup>

```python
i=0
for c in input():i-=c<'<'*i;print' '*i+c;i+=c>'<'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCstv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK0ydW2TbdRt1LUyrQuKMvNK1BWATO1k60xt22Q7oPj//@r6MUAAIdT/AwA)

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCstv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK0ydW0zFRLzUtRt1O2SrQuKMvNK1BXUtTK1k60ztW2T7YDi//@r68cAAYRQ/w8A)

Answer (score 15):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
ＦＳ¿⁼ι/↓¶/↘ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLQkuKQoMy9dQ1NTITNNQcO1sDQxp1gjU0dBSV8JKBYAlCzRsHLJL88DCsXkAQUVUnOKU5ElgjLTM0p0FDI1rf//j4mJ0dcHYgipr/9ft@y/bnEOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Supports extra `//`s. Explanation:

```
 Ｓ              Input string
Ｆ               Loop over each character
  ¿             If
    ι           Current character
   ⁼            Equals
     /          Literal /
      ↓¶        Move left
      ↓ /       Print a / downwards
         ↘ι     Else it's a \ so print that down and right
```

Comment: I think `↓¶` = "Move left" in the description isn't right.

Comment: @JonathanAllan That's right (newline printed down = move left), although it would probably be clearer to say "print `\n/` down"

Comment: I didn't say `print \n/ down` because I felt that it was more helpful to describe the effect of the code rather than its literal translation.

Comment: (Tongue in cheek: Describing the effect = `MyCode - Do the spec`). I [get it now though](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMqKDM9o0RHQSkkI7M4Jg@Ei0Aiekqa1r75ZakaRjpWLvnleZrWUPUgDoryFKAAUPX///91y/7rFucAAA) the effect is to move left; might be worth saying "Move left (by printing a newline with a downward printing direction)".

Comment: Most concise and self-explanatory of all!

Comment: 10 bytes: [`ＦＳ≡ι/↓¶/↘ι`](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLQkuKQoMy9dQ1NTobg8syQ5Q0EjU1Ohmis5sThVQUlfyUohAChfomHlkl@ep6OgFJOnr6RpzZWSmpZYmlOCIhuUmZ5RoqOQCZSu/f8/JiZGXx@IIaS@/n/dshwA) (Answer is too old for me to bother editing it.)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>14 13</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) (Use of `;"` in place of `ż` to allow yielding a list of lines and so use of `Ʋ`.)

```
=”\Ḥ’Ä_Ʋ⁶ẋ;"
```

A monadic Link that yields a list of lines.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UcPcmIc7ljxqmHm4Jf7YpkeN2x7u6rZW@n@4PfL//5iYGH19IIaQ@voA)**

#### How?

```
=”\Ḥ’Ä_Ʋ⁶ẋ;" - Link: list of characters, s    e.g. "\\\//\\/"
 ”\          - literal '\'                         '\'
=            - equal? (call this e)                [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
       Ʋ     - last four links as a monad - f(e)
   Ḥ         -   double (e)                        [2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0]
    ’        -   decrement                         [1, 1, 1,-1,-1, 1, 1,-1]
     Ä       -   cumulative sums                   [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2]
      _      -   subtract (e)                      [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2]
        ⁶    - literal ' '                         ' '
         ẋ   - repeat                              ["", " ", "  ", "  ", " ", " ", "  ", "  "]
           " - zip with:
          ;  -   concatenate (c from s)            ["\", " \", "  \", "  /", " /", " \", "  \", "  /"]
```

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UcPcmIc7ljxqmHm4Jf7YpkeN2x7u6j665//h9sj//2NiYvT1gRhC6usDAA), outputting as a list of lines, as [allowed by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/142655/draw-my-downslashes?noredirect=1#comment523389_142655)

Comment: I didn't do that because it [doesn't create a list of lines](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UcPcmIc7ljxqmHm4Jf7YpkeN2x7u6j665//h9qOTHu6c8f9/TEyMvj4QQ0h9fQA) and I can't think of a 12 that does...

Comment: [12 that does](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/2UcPcmIc7ljxqmHm4Jf7YpkeN2x7u6rZW@n@4/eikhztn/P8fExOjrw/EEFJfHwA)

Comment: So it does - I mentally rejected `;"` as doing the same as `ż` but of course, it doesn't >.< - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>23</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

*1 byte off thanks to [@Sanchises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises)*

```
fGqoEq1yd~h*YsGZ?c
```

Input is a string enclosed in single quotes.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P829MN@10LAypS5DK7LYPco@@f9/9ZiYGH39GP2YGHUA) Or verify test cases: [**1**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P829MN@10LAypS5DK7LYPco@@f9/9RgEUAcA), [**2**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P829MN@10LAypS5DK7LYPco@@f9/9ZiYGH19IIaQ@vrqAA), [**3**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P829MN@10LAypS5DK7LYPco@@f9/9Rh9EFQHAA).

#### Explanation

Consider input `'\\\//\/\\'` as an example.

```
f      % Implicit input. Array of indices of nonzeros. Since all chars in the input
       % have nonzero code point, this gives [1 2 ... n] where n is input length
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
G      % Push input again
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], '\\\//\/\\'
qo     % Subtract 1 from (the code-point) of each char and then compute modulo 2.
       % This transforms '\' into 1 and '/' into 0
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
Eq     % Double, subtract 1. This transforms 0 into -1
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1]
1y     % Push 1 and duplicate from below
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1], 1, [1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1]
d~     % Consecutive differences, logical negation: gives 1 if consecutive entries
       % are equal, 0 otherwise
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1], 1, [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
h      % Horizontally concatenate
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1], [1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1]
*      % Element-wise multiplication
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 1 1 0 -1 0 0 0 1]
Ys     % Cumulative sum
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3]
G      % Push input again
       % STACK: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9], [1 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 3], '\\\//\/\\'
Z?     % Build sparse matrix with those row indices, column indices, and values
       % STACK: [92  0  0;
                  0 92  0;
                  0  0 92;
                  0  0 47;
                  0 47  0;
                  0 92  0;
                  0 47  0;
                  0 92  0;
                  0  0 92]
c      % Convert to char. Char 0 is shown as space. Implicitly display
       % STACK: ['\  ';
                 ' \ ';
                 '  \';
                 '  /';
                 ' / ';
                 ' \ ';
                 ' / ';
                 ' \ ';
                 '  \']
```

Comment: One byte off by a slightly different algorithm to get your indices: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P829MN@10LAypS5DK7LYPco@@f9/9ZiYGH39GP2YGHUA "MATL – Try It Online")

Comment: @Sanchises Thanks for your very appropriate edits!

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
scanl(\x c->drop(sum[1|'/'<-c:x])(' '<$x)++[c])[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzvzg5MS9HI6ZCIVnXLqUov0CjuDQ32rBGXV/dRjfZqiJWU0NdQd1GpUJTWzs6OVYzOvZ/bmJmnoKtQnpqiU9mXqqCnZ2tQkFpSXBJkYKeQmleDlCsGMhK@x8TE6OvD8QQUl8fAA)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>66</s> <s>59</s> 63 bytes

*7 bytes saved thanks to [Justin Mariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner)

+4 bytes to fix `/\\/\\/` (noticed by [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil))*

```
f=([a,...z],b=a<'0')=>a?a.padStart(b+=k=a>'/')+`
`+f(z,b-!k):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLDsIwDET3uQUSUhLa2qwRKYdgSYri/qBF/SgNIIE4e0kq8MJjvZlxSw@aCtuMLumHsprnWokTxQDwyuJc0Z5vuVQpHQhGKo@OrBN5pG6KUo5cRoaZqBavOE9WN7njfB7tUFTTBJMrh7uDp21cJQSp1Kzf9DHQkSuuAs8njVpn0RovnfRwDJFakJTQDk1vdG/A2aYzRgYHN4xprRFDK1z/@VGPl43IQgQ9X5Qtlle2Qf97/gI)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

42 bytes of code + 2 for `-F` flag

```perl
say$"x($s+=$\eq$_&&$#i**m|/|).($\=$_)for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVJFqUJDpVjbViUmtVAlXk1NRTlTSyu3Rr9GU09DJcZWJV4zLb/Iwe3//5iYGH39mBgIBYT/8gtKMvPziv/r@prqGRga/Nd1AwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
ÇÈx<ηOs-W-ISú»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cPvhjgqbc9v9i3XDdT2DD@86tPv/f/2YGBACAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ç                # convert input string to a list of ascii codes
 È               # check each for evenness
  x              # push a doubled copy
   <             # decrement
    η            # compute prefixes
     O           # sum each prefix
      s          # swap the unaltered copy of evenness to the top
       -         # subtract from the prefix-sum list
        W-       # subtract the minimum value
          IS     # push input split to a list of chars
            ú    # pad each with the number of spaces computed
             »   # join on newline
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `/\\/\\/`.

Comment: `Ç¥.¥0<.SηOv¹Nèy<ú,` *sobbing in binary*

Comment: Well done! 

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>74</s> <s>88</s> <s>82</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 76 + 18 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)*

```cs
s=>s.Select((x,i)=>$"{x}".PadLeft((x-s[0])/45-~s.Take(i).Sum(y=>y<92?-1:1)))
```

Outputs a collection of strings, one for each line. Byte count also includes:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9RT8IwEH7vrziJD22ATow@KGzGEDAmmBgh8UF8qOWQxq7DtdMRwm@f3aaQyZdce/m@u/vupO3KJMUis8q8w3RjHcZ8osxnnxAjYrRrIfGPHyZao3QqMZbfocFUSbIl4CG1sBZuq7xmSlgnnJLwlagFPAhlKNtLh6IS48zIgXWp36ED9yOTxZiKN42/XBTBEsLChpHlUyxXoDTvKBZGp61tvmvxR7GY4NJRy2fiA6lifJrFdBNGm8HV@U23d91jbZp37cvZKwsuLts9xop@Y4PaCJRZZ66pfK@URqC0kiCEob8@0cif0Jsqg5QxOAnBZFqzRmPzxBLLegifpSr2bXyWTJR1lPFxko6EXNEcwmhv8Jwqh5VDzlj/aNhx2b@iHWlmO7Ir5gcQH0Hgo36DgARl7vnqJ5U0D34A)

Explanation for 77 byte answer:

```cs
s =>                              // Take input, a string
    s.Select((x, i) =>            // Replace every character with:
        $"{x}"                    //     The character as string
        .PadLeft(                 //     Pad with this many spaces:
            s.Take(i)             //         Take characters, in the input string, preceding current one
            .Sum(y =>             //         Sum them by:
                y < 92 ? -1 : 1   //             If it's a \ add 1, if / subtract 1
            )
            + (x - s[0]) / 45 + 1 //         If first slash is a / add one more space, if current slash is a \ add one more space (I got this through power of MATHS!)
                                  //         How I arrived at this function:
                                  //         + x / 48        If current slash is a \ add one more space
                                  //         - s[0] / 48 + 1 If the first slash is a / add one more space
        )
    )
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `/\\/\\/`.

Comment: @Neil thank you for pointing that out! Fixed.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but you can save a byte by changing `s.Take(i).Sum(y=>y<92?-1:1)+(x-s[0])/45+1` to `(x-s[0])/45-~s.Take(i).Sum(y=>y<92?-1:1)`

Comment: Nice one @KevinCruijssen !

Answer (score 3):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 96 bytes

```lua
c=0 for s in(...):gmatch(".")do c=c+(p==s and(s=="/"and-1or 1)or 0)p=s print((" "):rep(c)..s)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYtBCsMwDAS/InSSKJWTa0A/8cXIaRtoHWOn71e0h2Fg2O@/uJsu8DoHTDgaiQhv71@57EMoyPUEU3tQV51QWqWpignDnmt8Vg4s3CP2cbSLCAF5G3snY5HJe6vunmMppZxv)

Shortest one I could come up with in Lua. Input is taken from the command line.

This does use a few tricks:

1. `(...):gmatch(`
   This should be the shortest form of getting a single string into a Lua program from the command line. The `...` expression in Lua captures any excess parameters to a function that aren't specified in the function declaration and is used for varargs. Since the main body of a Lua program gets called as a function with the command line arguments as its parameters, the command line arguments will end up in `...`.
   The parentheses around it turn the potentially multi-valued `...` expression into a single-valued expression. Consider this (somewhat surprising) example:

   ```lua
   function multipleReturnValues()
       return "abc", "def"
   end
   print(  multipleReturnValues()  ) --This prints: abc    def
   print( (multipleReturnValues()) ) --This prints: abc
   ```
2. The Lua parser does not need any line terminators, or even whitespace between statements, as long as the two statements' tokens can be clearly separated and there's only one interpretation of the text that's valid Lua code.
3. Abusing `and`/`or` for "if x then value1 else value2" logic.
   Lua's `and` operator returns its first argument if it is falsy; otherwise, it returns its second argument. The `or` operator returns its first argument if it is truthy; otherwise, the second argument.
4. `p`doesn't need any initialization.
   `p==s` always has to be false in the first run of the loop, regardless of the input. Not setting `p` to any value before entering the loop (leaving it `nil`) will make that happen and save bytes, too.

Can anyone golf this (in Lua)?

Comment: I was able to save two bytes by using gsub instead of using gmatch. `c=0(...):gsub(".",function(s)c=c+(p==s and(s=="/"and-1or 1)or 0)p=s print((" "):rep(c)..s)end)`

Comment: Well, not that it matters. You could've easily saved two bytes by changing `gmatch(".")` to `gmatch"."` like you did in your next answer.

Comment: @QuertyKeyboard That's weird... I actually used gsub exactly like this in the first version of this code, but then switched to gmatch instead because it somehow turned out shorter. I don't know what I did different though, the file is overwritten unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 47 bytes

```
^|\\
 $&
+m`^( *)( /|\\)(/| \\)
$1$2¶$1$3
m`^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP64mJoZLQUWNSzs3IU5DQUtTQ0EfKKSpoV@jAKS4VAxVjA5tA5LGXEAFClz//8fExOjrx@gDtcUgABdEFCgMJvX1uUBK9IHiYBoA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^|\\
 $&
```

Add a space at the beginning of each line and before each `\`.

```
+m`^( *)( /|\\)(/| \\)
$1$2¶$1$3
```

Consider the first two characters of the string. If the first is a `/` then the indent needs to be decremented; this is achieved by including the preceding space in the capture (which always exists because the first stage added it); if the second is a `\\` then it needs to be incremented; this is achieved by including the space that the first stage added in the capture. Having given the second character the correct indent, the stage is repeated for the second and third character etc.

```
m`^
```

Remove the extra indent.

I've written a 94-byte version which (like my Charcoal answer) allows any combination of slashes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYs7DsJADER7n8KRDPJuJI/4lEgpcwhMtBQUFFAAZc6VA@Rii0kKphjpPc28bp/781o32pdqQvMkViSzbAnEoLYMajkpY3RP86T8A/cRiWQX64Pslz5S@3jHuDs1w9kdl3ixdo3lFRNRX6xWAIEOEP6h1YZe2v0L) Explanation:

```
.$
¶$.`$* $&
```

Get the ball rolling by taking the last slash and indenting it to the same position on its own line.

```
/
 /
```

Prefix spaces to all forward slashes so that they can be captured.

```
+`^(.*)( /|\\)¶( *)( \\|/)
$1¶$3$2¶$3$4
```

Repeatedly take the last slash of the input and align it on its own line with the slash on the line below.

```
+ms`^(?<!^[\\/].*) (?!.*^[\\/])
```

Delete any left-over indentation.

```
G`.
```

Delete the now empty input.

Answer (score 3):

## C (GCC), <strike>137</strike> <strike>134</strike> 97 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU3RCsMgDHzfV0ihYKrSDQaDivRD2j6UuHY@zA11eyn9dhe7g@OSXJJDtSLm7KTVC8fHHJoIW1GGJg5ukp5ECDdpRz5s7@B8WnhVN1jj6CtpxUUiaI7KQ287jsZcb9ArZTshytMIet8zXbHn7DwvxRxWlAxfPiZ2ZDVl9B0mYNuJEZw5a0s8GkobD7QtsRQV/J1wT5/gGe3t@Qc)

• 3 bytes thanks ATaco

• 37 bytes thanks to  Digital Trauma & ThePirateBay

```
i,d;f(char*s){char c=s[i],n=s[++i];if(c){printf("%*c%c\n",d+1,c);(c-n)?d:(c==47)?--d:++d;f(s);}}
```

Nothing too fancy just a simple recursive function that takes a string and prints out the slashes, note that the input needs to escape the backslashes first.

### Usage

```
f("\\\\\\//\\/\\\\",0,0);
```

### Ungolfed

This is for the old answer, view the try it online link for updated one!

```
f(char *s, i, d) {
    char c=s[i], n=s[++i];
    if(!c) return;
    for(int j=0; j<d; j++) printf(" ");
    printf("%c\n",c);
    f(s, i, (c!=n)?d:(c=='/')?d-1:d+1);
}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You can replace `c=='\0'` with `!c` for the same effect.

Comment: Awesome thanks just updated the solution!

Comment: Can you use `printf("%*s%c", n, "", c)` to print the the char c with n leading spaces?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can save few bytes by replacing `(c!=n)` with `c-n` and rearranging ternary expressions. Same with `(c=='/')`. Also, you can replace `'/'` with literal number `47`. I think it is 7 bytes in total.

Comment: The function signature is invalid

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##RUzLCkIhFPwX4YJPTsWNiJNf0m1xOWK5yELDTfTtprZoYB4Mw5C5EtVK2qHndFuTzOLtH4k7KzPMe7NFpyxZOx80tUopfKYQX56zSeaJlsi0M31w3GnGNAmBnxrwvobISRcxPmXBcRrsBpUKJ0LheTmHSx/X5Y@eARp/ClCh59YP/wI)

Comment: @ThePirateBay Can you help me golf it :P

Comment: [78 bytes, fancier output](https://tio.run/##RYzdCgIhEEZfJYRd/MWKjajJJ2m7WEYsL9ZiDW@iZzc1qIGZ7/AxHFRXxJxRWnAUb9PCI3u5@0Kt4VEPO7UBKwwaM@wllkoIeCw@PB0lHY8djoFIq@rDYSsJkcgYvLOHefKBokysOXmCJvVmDUL4EwL7WeKxOlbp7C@s7x1tUBx5/E9lrct@r9ZZVy59yw8)

Comment: @ASCII-only. [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzNDoMgEIRfpSHR8GeQa1eepPZgltByqDVguTT11SnowU12ZzKT/bB7IOaM0oKj@JwCj@zr3oFas/HYakDDoxBghcFWsyX4eXWUNDw2OM5E2s5spZCESGTwyx5ek58pysR2Gk@w47zpQQg/IJyMeK2ES7r5O5OOHrp81vpIdV9xeTyneqXKHleprKov@a5/). Always use `-` instead of `==`. Here is even better situation, because we can do bit hacking.

Comment: @ThePirateBay Oh true lol

Comment: @ThePirateBay & Digitial Trauma thanks I updated my answer!

Comment: @ASCII-only My C answer is only 60 bytes :)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>121</s> <s>118</s> <s>110</s> <s>109</s> 102 bytes

```java
a->{String r="";int s=0,p=0,i;for(char c:a){for(i=s+=p+(p=c-63)>>5;i-->0;r+=" ");r+=c+"\n";}return r;}
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*'s bit-wise magic. :)

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lY9NT8MwDIbv@xUmp1ajX0capRPizC4cGQfjdZDRpZGTTpqq/vaSdoXTJEQUW3Ycv3reI54xaW1tjvuvkRp0Dp5Rm34FoI2v@YBUw3ZqAV48a/MBFNEn8usbYCzD@xAiXOfRa4ItGFAwYlL1y3dWQsigBU7l9zaEloeWZw2gEuN@6rRya0V3ym7ykqqHYlOUSSF1klS55LUSIGJpFU01rcXOCDlw7Ts2wHIY5RXBdu9NQFhIzq3ewyl4ia4gM/Bi5OJ8fUrbzqc2jHxjIpNSJHY3j0h9@xRoH5nxEsXx7PovkSyb82@RZf@U@dkP6ebmsBrGbw)

```java
a->{                    // Method with char-array parameter and String return-type
  String r="";          //  Return-String
  int s=0,              //  Amount of spaces
      p=0,              //  Previous characters (starting at 0)
      i;                //  Index-integer
  for(char c:a){        //  Loop over the input
    for(i=s+=p+(p=c-63)>>5;
                        //   If the current does not equals the previous character
                        //    Leave `s` the same
                        //   Else-if it's a '\':
                        //    Increase `s` by 1
                        //   Else (it's a '/'):
                        //    Decrease `s` by 1
                        //   And set the previous character to the current in the process
        i-->0;r+=" ");  //   Append `r` with `s` amount of spaces               
    r+=c+"\n";          //   Append the character + a new-line to the result
  }                     //  End of loop
  return r;             //  Return result-String
}                       // End of method
```

Comment: 102 bytes: `a->{String r="";int s=0,p=0,i;for(char c:a){for(i=s+=p+(p=c-63)>>5;i-->0;r+=" ");r+=c+"\n";}return r;}`

Comment: @Nevay Thanks. I knew it could be shortened with some bitwise operations, but couldn't figure it out. Mainly because I forgot about trying the effects of `>>`/`>>>`/`<<`... I had only checked some things with `&`/`|`/`~`/`^`..>.>

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>122</s> 121 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe

```r
x=el(strsplit(scan(,""),""));n=seq(x);y=x>"/";for(i in n)cat(rep(" ",diffinv(y[n[-1]-1]+y[n[-1]]-1)[i]),x[i],"\n",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsMgEEX3PUWY1Qy1hK7FXiRmYRNDB@zEqhRzemug8N7nrX5qgZ/JpQPfvrz2NVOrxgfMJeUYuGBenKACoFPSYrL/YCV9mPqAEfS2J@SBZRBaXMHkI8IAauVtY/niMcl0u8@d6z9708QzqdpXgRVQ2UfT3xuM1p7Apf0A)

With extra whitespace:

```r
x = el(strsplit(scan(,""),""))
n = seq(x)
y = x>"/"
for(i in n) {
  cat(rep(" ", diffinv(y[n[-1]-1]+y[n[-1]]-1)[i]), x[i], "\n", sep="")
}
```

Explanation: This answer is based on the observation that the number of leading spaces changes each line by -1, plus the number of `/` in the previous and current lines.

If we have N slashes, the variable `y` is a vector of length N, with 1 for each position with `\`, 0 otherwise. Therefore, to get the change in number of leading spaces per line, we calculate `y[1:(N-1)] + y[2:N] - 1`. The function `diffinv` converts these differences into a sequence, starting with 0. The rest is just a matter of assembling each line as the required number of trailing spaces, followed by the relevant slash and a newline.

Comment: huh. I took a quite different approach for [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYw9D8IwDER3fkXwZFeuoIihQpSduWzAUEKtemhS5eP3h3DDSe/0dKGIGYpkZ5N6h5HEB1SjznQXZ5cp1InslDDMG4IBtnmNeUWLR95/VQRxvLY5Sf/wd5eqfTv31JzajqgZ6alv4pg/MdUjVlZi2AHHeRsAqAjCq@bwr4o/) which makes me wonder if we could combine our approaches. (nice use of `diffinv` ;) Also you can set `y=x>")"` for -1 byte

Comment: @Giuseppe You should post that as a separate answer, it's a different enough approach. Yours is a nice way of avoiding having to do `strsplit`, which is always a killer. You can also make use of the famous `diffinv`!

Comment: Also I think if you put `library(methods)` in the header (which should be OK w/o penalty since that package is part base R), you can use `el`. Also, `diffinv` turned out to be just as long as `cumsum`! :)

Comment: Yes, I was just realising that too, it doesn't quite work in that context

Comment: well, I came up with [a workaround](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142706/67312), but yeah, that `*S` screws things up.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 175 bytes (174 chars + 1 flag)

Run with `-c` flag.

```
{(({})<(())>){({}[()]<([{}])>)}{}(({}<>{}<><({}<>)((()()()()()){})>)<{({}[()]<((((()()()()){}){}){})>)}>{})<>}<>{}{({}<>)(({})(())){({}[()]<([{}]())>)}{}{<>{}<>(<{}>)}{}<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU5BCsNACPzOeAj7AfEjMYckUCgtPfQqvt2qaUgpu7Kj48zs9l7vr@n2XB8RBpgTA0RClngGLYzZfMmBmxfPUsWNCLl7HkqtEF86XGxxx00fqRBpIzttclSxf6n9kcy1IxRs3n2rI1R1DB36@35RTPsH)

### Explanation

```
{ for each char in the input...
  (({})<(())>){({}[()]<([{}])>)}{} push 1/-1 for backslash/slash
  ((
   {}<>{}<> add the 1/-1 to a running total
   <
    ({}<>) move slash/backslash to other stack
    ((()()()()()){}) newline
   >
  )<{({}[()]<((((()()()()){}){}){})>)}>{}) spaces
  <>
}<>{} end for
reverse data order, removing one space before backslash
{({}<>)(({})(())){({}[()]<([{}]())>)}{}{<>{}<>(<{}>)}{}<>}<>
```

Comment: I always upvote brain-flak. :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), <strike>80</strike> 76 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to manatwork

```
puts"\\";$*[i=0].chars.each_cons 2{|b,c|puts" "*(b==c ?b==?/?i-=1:i+=1:i)+c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgpJkbJWkUrOtPWIFYvOSOxqFgvNTE5Iz45P69Ywai6JkknuQasTkFJSyPJ1jZZwR5I2uvbZ@raGlplaoMITe3k2v///8fExOjrx@jHxAAA)

Explanation:

```
puts "\\"           # Output the first backslash
$*[i=0].            # Get the first argument and set i to 0
chars.              # Go through every individual character,
each_cons 2 { |b,c| # In pairs to compare easily
                    #
    puts " " *      # Decide how many padding spaces to use based on the value
                    # of i. The expression inside the parenthesis will return
                    # i but before that, it will increment/decrement i based
                    # on what the previous character was.
                        #
    ( b==c ?            # if b == c
        b==?/ ?         #   if b == "/" (Going to the left)
            i-=1        #       return decremented i
            :           #   else        (Going to the right)
            i+=1        #       return incremented i
        :               # else
        i) +            #   return i
                    #
                c   # Finally, write the second of the characters that we're
}                   # iterating through.
```

Comment: Which Ruby version? The 2.3.3 I have demands parenthesis around parameter when code block follows: `.each_cons(2){…}`. In change you can save by replacing `.each_char` → `.chars`.

Comment: @manatwork My ruby version is 2.4.1. Thanks for the suggestion about chars, I didn't know about that one.

Comment: You can save another two bytes by moving `i+=` to the beginning of the nested ternary expression, and ending it with `-1:1:0`.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 60 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=1;*s;s++)printf("%*c\n",*s%2?--i:i++,*s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsMgDMdfZRQKahTbHZuVPci6Qwm4Kawr2nkZe3an9tBA8v@A/Eg9iFKyaBg9Zy8C/5q3Z3bsUQQMAHz1dtkMa1pB09JIEdrzVSk7WIAcOP6Sw9dsF0Yy8soQESvEjR0CuAvhAQlDgZzizd25NGzX9bOVR9Z3BZemY4rXOu9@tU66@NxX/QM)

Comment: [TIO](https://tio.run/##RYzNCsMgDMdfZRQKahTbHZuVPci6Qwm4Kawr2nkZe3an9tBA8v@A/Eg9iFKyaBg9Zy8C/5q3Z3bsUQQMAHz1dtkMa1pB09JIEdrzVSk7WIAcOP6Sw9dsF0Yy8soQESvEjR0CuAvhAQlDgZzizd25NGzX9bOVR9Z3BZemY4rXOu9@tU66@NxX/QM)

Comment: @ASCII-only you're welcome

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 98 bytes

```
++++++++[->++++<]<<<,[[->+++++++++++<<+>]>-----[>+>+<<[-]]>-[->>.<+<]>[-<+>]<<<<.[-]>++++++++++.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtRCoAwDEMPtHW9QOhFun6oIIjgh@D5a4b78EEb0ibrvRzX/mxnZpm42BAEgOrTTYBiYTJwK0bvEjwwZQ3smMuIsIrG16/bamT23lU531Z9AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
ƛ\/=&-ð¥*n+,C₂&+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%5C%2F%3D%26-%C3%B0%C2%A5*n%2B%2CC%E2%82%82%26%2B&inputs=%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%5C%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ                # Map by...
    &-           # Decrement register by 
 \/=             # (is a forward-slash)
      ð¥*        # (register) spaces
         n+,     # prepended to n and outputted
              &+ # Increment register by
            C₂   # (is a backslash)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
j.u+?qeNY?>Y\/+PNdPPNPNYtzhz
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.u%2B%3FqeNY%3F%3EY%5C%2F%2BPNdPPNPNYtzhz&input=%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C&debug=0)

Comment: You can save a byte by using `Q` instead: [`j.u+?qeNY?>Y\/+PNdPPNPNYtQh`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j.u%2B%3FqeNY%3F%3EY%5C%2F%2BPNdPPNPNYtQh&input=%27%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%27&debug=0).

Comment: [26 bytes](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VzIqHN%3DZ%3FqH%5C%5ChZtZ%29%2B%2adZN%3DHN&input=%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 119 bytes

```r
function(s)for(i in 1:nchar(s))cat(rep(" ",cumsum(c(0,!diff(S<-(utf8ToInt(s)>48)*2-1))*S)[i]),substr(s,i,i),"
",sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy7DoJAEAB7v@LcapcsOTEWxIi9NXZigScbtuAg9/h@vDjlZDJhF9Ptkr1LunqMJGtANepNc/VuHkNR5MaEYdoQDLDLS8wLOjzx8asi2N9qzEna5/rwqdT3S0vVuW6Iqp5e@iaO@RNTGbGyEsMBOE5bB0C7IAwFO/yx1hb3Aw)

This differs somewhat from [user2390246's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142696/67312). They each iterate over the string, printing out a certain number of space characters and then the appropriate `/\` character.

However, I avoided splitting the string, opting instead to replace the characters with their UTF-8 encoding value instead, which then allows me to do arithmetic on the numbers directly, which saved me just a few bytes.

Comment: Just been pondering this some more, I think there is an error in your algorithm: [TIO](https://tio.run/##HYy7DsIwDEV3viJ4sitXoYihQpSduWzAUEItPDSt8vj@EHGWKx1dnVDEDEWyd0lXj5FkDahGvenO3n2nUBW5KWGYNwQD7PIS84IOD7z/qAjieGlzkv6@3nyq7@upp@bYdkTNSA99Ecf8jqmGWFmJYQcc520AoCII9lmx9j/V/AA)

Comment: @user2390246 I fixed it! I had some misplaced parentheses, but now the `diffinv` definitely won't work here.

Comment: what about https://tio.run/##HYy7DsIwEAR/xaS6i2yZJBQpAj11QkUokMlJV8QOfkj@e2MxxUo7K60vJK6FkjWRnYWA5DywYCvC9oU8qRRpXNzdxrohmncEtnFxj6rBgN8OGHpp0h7SXvtZnj5MBPOkIN8uI7a96hDbGZ/8Qplrym6oR4WgWSt6/aO1brD8AA

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>88</s> 84 bytes

Improved version (-4 bytes thanks to QuertyKeyboard)

```lua
s=""g=s.gsub g(...,".",function(c)s=g(g(g(s,"\\"," "),"/?$",c)," /","/")print(s)end)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhRCgIxDESvUgY/GgjJCcpeJD9atSxIV8z2/LHWecMwM69xjfACtOLSfNxSyyLCEPBz9HruR8@VvLT8wxlmYCQQQ7cLuM6SdF4Ken/2fmanR79TRNiU6srJsq6tf5l9AQ)

## Original version (88 bytes)

Another attempt in Lua, this time with a completely different approach using string manipulation instead of a counter variable.

```lua
s=""for c in(...):gmatch"."do s=s:gsub("\\"," "):gsub("/?$",c):gsub(" /","/")print(s)end
```

Ungolfed:

```lua
s = ""
for c in string.gmatch((...), ".") do --for each character in the input
  --s contains the output from the previous iteration
  s = s:gsub("\\", " ") --Replace backslash with space -> indent by 1
  s = s:gsub("/?$", c) --Remove any / at the end of the string and append c to the string
  s = s:gsub(" /", "/") --Remove a single space in front of any / -> un-indent by 1
  print(s)
end
```

There's one interesting thing in the code: `(...):gmatch"."`
This uses some quirks in the Lua parser. When Lua encounters a piece of code in the form `func "string"`, it'll convert this to `func("string")`. This is so that one can write `print "string"` to print a constant string and it only works with a single string literal after the function. Anything else will give a syntax error. However, this syntactic sugar also works with function calls in the middle of an expression, and more surprising, it works just fine together with the `:` method call syntactic sugar. So in the end, Lua will interpret the code like this:

```lua
(...):gmatch"."
-> (...):gmatch(".")
-> string.gmatch((...), ".")
```

<s>If anyone can think of a way to remove one of the three gsub calls, please tell me.</s>

Comment: I was disappointed to find that my gsub trick I commented in your other answer didn't quite work for this one. It actually ended up adding one byte. However, I wouldn't give up that easily. First, I tried to store gsub as a variable to shorten the code. To my surprise, my code was exactly the same amount of bytes - 88. However, I realized that with gsub being saved, my gsub trick could now work! Here's my code that shaved off 4 bytes: `s=""g=s.gsub g(...,".",function(c)s=g(g(g(s,"\\"," "),"/?$",c)," /","/")print(s)end)`

Comment: @QuertyKeyboard Yup, I also tried storing gsub in a variable before the loop and then using it instead of writing gsub three time, and I was just as surprised to see it making absolutely no difference. Combining the "gsub instead of loop" and "store gsub" tricks is really neat, didn't think of that one! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 60/65 bytes

I tried shorter C# version

```
s=>{int i=0;return s.Select(x=>"".PadLeft(x<92?--i:i++)+x);}
```

as there was stated: "This also means that every input will start with a backslash."
Or slighly longer which solve starting "/"

```
s=>{int i=s[0]&1;return s.Select(x=>"".PadLeft(x<92?--i:i++)+x);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/BTsMwDL3nK8wOqNFYCtygaxGaNoQ0JMQmcWAcQuYxS206khSGpn57SVvYVPYkJ8579rOj7EDlBqvCkn6H2bd1mIkp6Y@IMS0ztBup8I8f5WmKylGurbhDjYYU2zHwUKm0Fm6bvGVqWCcdKfjMaQkPknTA99KhqMak0GponfE7nMH9WBcZGvmW4i@XJLCCuLJxsiPtgGL7cv56ehEZdIXRYMUM672CbZz0euJRLqe48q/h1eXNYEDX1O/z/pZHZRV1prbmQHpTuK7ytaYUIQgaCWIY@R/nKYon9N6kMeAcTmLQRZryTmP3WzVWrYmYG8p8m5jnU7Iu4GKSm7FU62ALcbIf8GzIYTNhy3l0ZHZc9q@oZN2sZGW1OID5CEMf7RmGLKxzzzc3a6RF@AM)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 31 bytes

```apl
{↑⍵,¨⍨' '/¨⍨{⍵-⍨+\¯1+2×⍵}⍵='\'}
```

[Try it here!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2191%u2375%2C%A8%u2368%27%20%27/%A8%u2368%7B%u2375-%u2368+%5C%AF1+2%D7%u2375%7D%u2375%3D%27%5C%27%7D%27%5C%5C%5C//%5C/%5C%5C%27&run)

Comment: `{↑⍵↑¨⍨a-1-+\¯1*a←⍵='\'}`

Answer (score 2):

## QBasic, 79 bytes

```
DO
c$=INPUT$(1)
IF"/">c$THEN END
c=2*ASC(c$)-139
i=i+c+p
?SPC(i\90);c$
p=c
LOOP
```

This program prints the slashes as you type them. To quit, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or anything earlier in the ASCII table than `/`).

[image: Downslashes program in action]

#### Explanation

With the variables `i` and `p` implicitly initialized to `0`, we enter an infinite loop. `INPUT$(1)` reads one character from keyboard input. If this character is less than forward slash, `END` the program. Otherwise, we calculate `c` such that an input of `/` gives `c=-45` and `\` gives `c=45`. We then add `c` and `p` (the **p**revious value) to `i` (the **i**ndent).

If `p` and `c` are the same, they add together to change `i` by either `-90` or `+90`. If they are different, they cancel out and do not change `i`. We then print `i\90` spaces followed by the character. (We use integer division because the value of `i` is actually going to be `45`, `135`, etc., since `p` is `0` on the first iteration instead of `-45`.)

Finally, set `p=c` for the next iteration, and loop.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 33 bytes

Includes `+1` for the `n` option

```
perl -nE 's%.%say$"x(l^$&?--$a:$a++).$&%eg' <<< '\\\//\/\\'
```

Where it not for the fact that `-F` counts as `+3` this would be `32`:

```
echo -n '\\\//\/\\' | perl -F -E 'say$"x(l^$_?--$a:$a++).$_ for@F'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 43 bytes

```sh
for c (`fold -1`)echo ${(l/#c%2?w--:++w/)c}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IIVlBIyEtPydFQdcwQTM1OSNfQaVaI0dfOVnVyL5cV9dKW7tcXzO59v//mJgYfX0ghpD6@gA)

Explanation:

- `fold -1`: line-wrap the input to a width of 1 (i.e., insert a line-break between every character)
- ``` for c (``) ```: for each character `$c`:

  - `${c}`: take the character,
  - `(l//)`: left-padded with spaces to the width of:

    - `#c`: the character code of `$c`
    - `%2`: modulo 2 (this is 1 for `/` and 0 for `\`)
    - `?`: if 1 then:

      - `w--`: decrement `$w` (and return the original value)
    - `:`: else:

      - `++w`: increment `$w` (and return the mutated value)
    - note that `$w` starts at 0 implicitly
  - `echo`: print; we can't use the 2 bytes shorter `<<<` since its argument is evaluated in a sub-shell so the mutation of `$w` has no effect

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 33 bytes

First attempt, will golf.

```
jsMC,*L;+ZsM._*VqVtzztMxL"/ \\"zz
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jsMC%2C%2aL%3B%2BZsM._%2aVqVtzztMxL%22%2F+%5C%5C%22zz&input=%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C&debug=0).

Comment: [my first attempt](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JZVzIqJNIqJ%5C%5C%3DhZ%29.%3F%3DtZ%29%29%2B%2adZN%3DJN&input=%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C&debug=0) 32 bytes

Comment: [second attempt](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JZVzIqJN%3DZ%3FqJ%5C%5ChZtZ%29%2B%2adZN%3DJN&input=%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C&debug=0) 28 bytes

Comment: [third attempt](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VzIqHN%3DZ%3FqH%5C%5ChZtZ%29%2B%2adZN%3DHN&input=%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%2F%5C%5C&debug=0) 26 bytes

Comment: *pinged* @maltysen

Comment: @StanStrum at this point, u can just post it as your own answer

Comment: right mate see you there

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 14 bytes

```
\ÓçÜ/j>G
ç¯/<G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P@bw5MPLD8/Rz7Jz5zq8/NB6fRt3oGBMjL5@jH5MDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 40 + 2 bytes

```
/\//&&$.--,say($"x$.,$_),/\\/&&$.++for@F
```

You need the `-F` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>34</s> 38 + 1  bytes

to handle the two cases

```
s,(/)|.,$"x($1?$c&&--$c:$c++).$&.$/,ge
```

to be run with `-p` option

```
s,(/)|.,$"x($1?--$c:$c++).$&.$/,ge
```

EDIT: following comment doesn't work when first character is `/`

```
s,(/)|.,$"x($1?$c--:++$c).$&.$/,ge
```

however output will be shifted one character on the right if first char is `\`

Comment: Doesn't work for `/\\/\\/`.

Comment: With the updated question your original `34` solution is now perfectly valid

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

Port from Rod's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142657/66418).

```
VQ=-Z<N\<+*ZdN=+Z>N\<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzQVjfKxi/GRlsrKsXPVjvKDsj@/189Bgj0wYT6fwA)

Comment: Invalid, prints [extra leading space on the first line if the string starts with ``\``. BTW where is your code?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder fixed

Answer (score 1):

**VBA (Excel), 181 bytes**

```
Sub q()
a = Cells(1, 1)
For x = 1 To Len(a)
c = Mid(a, x, 1)
If c = "\" Then: Debug.Print b & c: b = b + " "
If c = "/" Then: b = Left(b, Len(b) - 1): Debug.Print b & c
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You can golf this down significantly without changing your algorithm by taking advantage of the autoformatting nature of Excel VBA and by use of `[...]` notation: I got it down to 128 Bytes  `Sub q`
`For x=1To[Len(A1)]`
`c=Mid([A1],x,1)`
`If c="\"Then Debug.?b;c:b=b+" "`
`If c="/"Then b=Left(b,Len(b)-1):Debug.?b;c`
`Next`
`End Sub`

Comment: Thank you for golfing my script. I learned something from this and will apply in the future. :) Didn't know I can use that to fetch data directly to the cells. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>16</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
{└=-:↕PFoF┘=+
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTJDJTdCJXUyNTE0JTNELSUzQSV1MjE5NVBGb0YldTI1MTglM0Qr,inputs=JTVDJTVDJTVDLy8lNUMvJTVDJTVD) - expects input on the stack, so for ease-of-use `,` is added

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>74</s></sub> 72 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
For i=1To[Len(A1)]:c=Mid([A1],i,1):s=s+(c="/"):?Spc(s)c:s=s-(c="\"):Next
```

#### Example I/O

```vb
[A1]="\\\//\\/\//\\///"
For i=1To[Len(A1)]:c=Mid([A1],i,1):s=s+(c="/"):?Space(s)c:s=s-(c="\"):Next
\
 \
  \
  /
 /
 \
  \
  /
  \
  /
 /
 \
  \
  /
 /
/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Implicit](//git.io/sS), 25 bytes

```
~.(´?`/ò](0ß´);@ß1?`\ó~.ö
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9zaW1wbGVzdGFja///fi4owrg/YC/Dsl0oMMOfwrgpO0DDnzE/YFzDs34uw7b//1xcXC8)

Ungolfed/explanation:

```
~.         read input, increment
(          do..while top of stack truthy
 ´         decrement

 ?`/{      if input equal to /
   ]´[      decrement memory
 }

 ](0       pull memory, do..while truthy
  @32       print a space
  ´         decrement
 );        pop

 @@10      print input, print a newline

 ?`\{      if input equal to \
   ].[      increment memory
 }

 ~.        read input, increment
)          loop
&          exit (avoid implicit output)
```

Note that `ß` is equal to `@32`, `ò` is equal to `]´[`, `ó` is equal to `].[`, and `ö` can be used in place of `)&` when at the end of a program.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 78 bytes

```
a,x='',0
for i in input():x+=((1*i!='/')-(1*i=='/'))*(a==i);print(' '*x+i);a=i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYcxDoAgEAR7X4HVHaA5jZ3mfkJDY7wGCcEEX4@oyc5kNt75OMNSqx8KAwxTt59JiZLQFq@Mei2WEWcjPQOBHt/kL7VBzyx6i0lCRlBgim3Xs9TqnCNq/CZ6AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 151 bytes

```
>->++++[>++++++++<-]>>+[[-]>[-]>,[<+<+>>-]<<[>++++>-[<->-----]+<[<<<<+[>+<-]>[<+>>.<-]>>>>-]>[<<<<<[>+<-]>[<+>>.<-]->>>>->]<<<.>>>++++++++++.[-]>]<<<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1LCsMwDEQPpMq@wDAXkb1oA4EQ6KLQ87saBbrIA33QaKTX53m89@92rkWnJVFZwCdpEVkUj4DBSJ/AtUQPOF1MQyCRXb7QZqsLcrBE3EUvlXkQLTv70/RQY8y1xhi9Z1y59x8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>96</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

Awesome -25 solution by [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

And another -1 by [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat). ASCII bit hacks ftw

```c
c;p;main(i){for(;read(0,&c,1);printf("%*c\n",i,p=c))c-p?:c&1?--i:++i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEAXQuwSF1oi1bQgvMhv5ZcwiE2kXnd3egzuB1sCFr6jZqH3TXQ3XI@5mpgG0WC5V85NM14@Q3JFS2WAtXAkrhiU4p@s0KX@tiYj34kV@)

**Ungolfed**

```c
c; /* character */
p; /* previous character */

main(i /* indent */)
{
    for (; read(0, &c, 1); printf("%*c\n", i, p = c))
        c - p ? : c & 1 ? --i : ++i;
}
```

**Explanation**

`read` takes `1` byte from the file descriptor `0` (`stdin`) and stores it in `c`.

`c - p` checks if `c` and `p` are different. `c & 1` checks if `c` is a forward slash. So the entire conditional increments the indent if the character and the previous character are both backslashes, and decrements the indent if they're both forward slashes.

Then we print `c` with `i` leading spaces. We also assign `p = c` for the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>28</sup> <sup>27</sup> 22 bytes

```
({."0~+/\-0&<)_1^'\'=]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Nar1lAzqtPVjdA3UbDTjDePUY9RtY/9rcqUmZ@QrpCmox8TE6OvH6MfEqEOE1HV1ddWRZUEAl5y@vr76fwA)

*Thanks to Bubbler for catching a bug and for -6 bytes!*

Comment: I think first column is truncated? Fixing it and using `_1^` gives [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/q/WUDOriDbX1Yxx0jIBkvKGulUOceoy6bex/Ta7U5Ix8hTQF9ZiYGH39GP2YGHWIkLqurq46siwI4JLT19dX/w8A).

Comment: Thanks.  The _1 trick is more elegant anyway.

Comment: I got it down to [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##dczBCsIwDAbge58i7LBsbGlaj8VJUfAkHrya2YM4ZJc9gOCr13YKDsFAcsj3J2MsNA7QOUBowYBLTRp2p8M@Vg9dmGfDQqZc18FeULDrIxy3GtRspkrqe/qqWujZZSbfmHIzB/gnEGw@b1dpBkvOf17U6na9TzAAigizsAi@V0hEuNRc/4yZMb4A).

Comment: There is golfed... and then there is Bubbler-ed!

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>71</s> 69 bytes

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```powershell
$z=92
$args|%{$i+=($x=2*($_-eq92)-1)*($z-ne$_)
' '*$i+($z=$_)
$i+=$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V@lytbSiEslsSi9uEa1WiVT21ZDpcLWSEtDJV43tdDSSFPXUBPIqdLNS1WJ1@RSV1DXAioCCtiCuCD1KhW1/2u5uNRjEEBdB8zV1wdiCKmvDxbTh0J1oF1caippCg7x1urqXLX/AQ)

Takes input by splatting. This also saves us two bytes because we can just treat it as an int instead of writing `'\'` which we do twice.

Comment: nice. `($x=2*($_-eq92)-1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 47 bytes

```powershell
switch($args){'\'{' '*$i+++$_}'/'{' '*--$i+$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/b@4PLMkOUNDJbEovVizWj1GvVpdQV1LJVNbW1slvlZdH8LX1QWKAPm1/2u5uNRjEEBdB8zV1wdiCKmvDxbTh0L1GtVqLjWVNAWHeGt1da7a/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>110</s> <s>92</s> 90 bytes

```
listen to S
cut S
Y's -1
while S
roll S in C
let Y be+C's "\"
say " "*Y+C
let Y be-C's "/"
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

```
listen to S     :Read input string into variable S
cut S           :Split into an array
Y's -1          :Initialise Y as -1
while S         :While S is not empty
roll S in C     :  Pop the first element into variable C
let Y be+       :  Increment Y by
  C's "\"       :    C is equal to "\"
say " "*Y+C     :  Output Y spaces & C
let Y be-       :  Decrement Y by
  C's "/"       :    C is equal to "/"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 125 bytes

```
=LET(q,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),x,MID(A1,q,1),REPT(" ",MMULT(IF(TRANSPOSE(q)>q,,1),IF(q=1,,(INDEX(x,q-1)="\")-(INDEX(x,q)="/"))))&x)
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnD0x0tV0UCAauooY?e=N13qHL)

This is a port of [Taylor Scott's VBA answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142927/101349).

### Explanation

- `=LET(q,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),` q = vertical array `[1..LEN(A1)]`
- `x,MID(A1,q,1),` x = The characters in `A1` in a vertical array
- `IF(q=1,,(INDEX(x,q-1)="\")-(INDEX(x,q)="/"))` the change in the number of spaces from the prior line; +1 if the prior line was "", -1 if the current line is "/"
- `IF(TRANSPOSE(q)>q,,1)` a lower triangular matrix of 1s
- `MMULT(~,~)` matrix multiply the change array and the lower triangular matrix to get the number of spaces for each line
- `REPT(" ",~)&x)` for each line output the number of spaces & characters

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
jm?qd\\+*;~hZd+*;=tZ
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=jm%3Fqd%5C%5C%2B%2a%3B%7EhZd%2B%2a%3B%3DtZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%22%0A%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%22%0A%22%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%2F%2F%5C%5C%5C%5C%2F%2F%2F%22%0A%22%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%2F%5C%5C%2F%22&debug=0)

The other two existing Pyth answers use different approaches (and an older version of the language).

###### Explanation:

```
jm?qd\\+*;~hZd+*;=tZ   | Full program
jm?qd\\+*;~hZd+*;=tZdQ | with implicit variables added
-----------------------+------------------------------------------------
 m                   Q | For each character d in the input:,
  ?qd\\                |  if d is '\',
        *;             |   create a string of n spaces, where n is
          ~hZ          |    Z, but then store Z + 1 in Z (Z begins as 0)
       +     d         |   add d to the end of the string
  ?                    |  otherwise,
              +*;   d  |   do the same, but with (below) spaces
                 =tZ   |    Z - 1, stored in Z
j                      | Join the results by newline.
```

Comment: The test suite's input is missing a trailing `"`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 67 bytes

```julia
s->(x=[s...];@.println(lpad(x,$cumsum(1-2(x<'0')-[0;$diff(x)]%2))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LDsIgEEXX8hVkUuOQUFCXvuLWlR@ALBoNCaZiU0rk7ytYUx@XGcjM3Jww11DbahF7Q7e09@UO41Z5IYRe70XTWtfVDuumumDkxTncfLjholxi3MzmM1aq@bq4WGMwMj1dsqTeuiZ0PtEUmcDpS1LmzHd6x5ASOJm01QMGS@qNja/RYPvhffRLSAj5R85YCYRoQhS@txKo4JD/ugLuOQCHY@hepWbcoGecvpwIJ5cPMEbNvaWeWkeHJXX/BA)

- -3 bytes thanks to @MarcMush: replace `isodd(_)` with `(_.%2)`
- -6 bytes thanks to @MarcMush: use `@.` to vectorize multiple expressions
- -3 bytes thanks to @amelies: replace string repeats with `lpad`
- -1 byte thanks to @MarcMush: replace `'x=='/'` with `x<'0'`

Comment: I think you can use `.%2` instead of isodd

Comment: Also maybe a `@.` instead of all the broadcasting

Comment: 72 bytes using `lpad` and removing one `*`: `s->(x=[s...];@.println(lpad(x,$cumsum(1-2(Int(x)%2)-[0;$diff(x)]÷45))))`

Comment: You can use `x<'0'` instead of `x=='/'`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
Cæ:d⌐¦+↳
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJDw6Y6ZOKMkMKmK+KGsyIsIuKBiyAjIGpvaW4gYnkgbmV3bGluZXMgKG91dHB1dHMgbGlzdCBvZiBsaW5lcykiLCJbXCJcXFxcXCIsXCJcXFxcXCIsXCIvXCIsXCJcXFxcXCIsXCJcXFxcXCIsXCIvXCIsXCIvXCJdIl0=) Outputs as a list of lines, formatting in footer

```
C        # Charcodes: "/" -> 47, "\" -> 92
 æ       # Are prime? "/" -> 1, "\" -> 0
   d⌐    # Double and take one's complement "/" -> -1, "\" -> 1
     ¦   # Cumulative sums
      +  # Add...
 æ:      # Is prime? (indents "/" by one extra space)
       ↳ # Pad to these lengths
```

Comment: are you literally trying to make this slow? `∷` is much faster than a primality test :p

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>86</s> <s>76</s> 75 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Neil.*

```python
p,i='',0
for c in input():i+={'\\\\':1,'//':-1}.get(p+c,0);print' '*i+c;p=c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU49D4IwEN37Ky4sB4IWHEsYcXVxdDG1ShMDzVEixPjbsbSExZfL5b13n2ayTdceZ9ndFVRAURTNJtMVYpazR0cgQbcuzGDjROi0@uDVAUWRIeco9sX38FQ2NqnM8qQ0pFuLgDudytJUcnb7GLM0CQYO70a/FFxoUEEvUKOSsJzfHL@EqVEqY6E@n2qijsKAufX97D/4B7K1wLnPG3F/MuTBWdtWFXzPF/UD)

<s>Fairly lame approach, I will try to golf the mapping at least.</s> NVM I got rekt by another answer. >_>

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 165 bytes

```rust
fn f(s:&str){let(_,a)=s.chars().fold((0,"".to_string()),|(i,r),c|(if c<'<'{i-1}else{i+1},format!("{}{}{}\n",r," ".repeat(if c<'<'{i-1}else{i}),c)));println!("{}",a)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BDoIwDD3rV2AP2sbJ5Cr4JyRkwU2XwCDbPM19Ow4O6IG2aZu@vvbZt/PTpEym0N2OzlsKnfTYMEF3l7cvYR1SrobugXhlALkfmrSlzROJ2Ac1s8TaVFXWVqfqFPSliLJzMuhzEZkabC/8ASHE2WsDzDLIILdylMJv0WK6R0TlmJ74zixcSHLirLIX2iBlYb9TCPWmAZV/KOdLXhvOfzhfY57F6Qs)

It's an adaptation of Rod's answer in Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

#### c64 basic v2, <strike>71</strike> <strike>70</strike> 61 bytes

```
1rEs:x=1024:fOy=1tolE(s):a=aS(mI(s,y,1)):pOx,a:x=x-165+a*2:nE
```

Input can be given as

```
0dA"\\/\/\\/\//"
```

If the string is longer as 25, the program will overwrite its own memory. And we won't do that, because basic programs overwriting themselves with `POKE`s contradict the OO paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](https://tio.run/##FYxLCgIxEAWvEgNDnMmQzzbxd4GcwHYxiKMNg4oRXDTt1WPL2xWv6vpY5np@4fPdWvRkvNlyF1PNR6pMzq0hr/YubCiPQaigA@wYZ/7ccLmcQio5Jsw0Eg7cpYmKNcoMqESRGJMG0PJXVsNdW/ZTX6xIGb@9eOxbA//fDw) - 117 bytes

```
1/{'/'=}%1:s;[{s}{..(\;!?.0<{;,0:s;}{.@\>}if}while]0:M;1:i;{,{i*}%:a{M+' '*i 0<{'/'}{"\\"}if +"\n"+}/a)M+:M;;i~):i;}/
```

[Ungolfed version](https://tio.run/##HcxNCsIwEAXg/ZwiBkpsU5J22/h3gZ7AcVHE2oGiYgUXw3j1OLp78N73rvd5XM5PerxybiO76LZSQNstCY68CDAYE8Ia02ofmg2nutFKOBxwJzSCwHui@XKCpuuTMkp/UTNVUnQD994ZV5FRqtfCFtGqM97izXqJuh3K3itOGulT/h4k5oyIMWJE/AI)

```
1/{'/'=}%
1:s;
[{s}
{
  ..(\;!?.0<{;,0:s;}{.@\>}if
}
while]
0:M;
1:i;
{
  ,{i*}%:a{M+' '*i 0<{'/'}{"\\"}if +"\n"+}/
  a)M+:M;;
  i~):i;
}/
```

At first glance it looked easy... it took me 2.5 hours. Probably there is room for improvement, perhaps tomorrow I'll do some optimization.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>49</s> 48 bytes

Takes input as an array of individual characters and outputs an array of lines.

```js
a=>a.map(c=>" ".repeat(x+=d=c>'/',x-=!d)+c,x=-1)
```

Saved a byte borrowing a trick from the other JS solution.

---

### Try it

```js
f=
a=>a.map(c=>" ".repeat(x+=d=c>'/',x-=!d)+c,x=-1)
o.innerText=[String.raw`\\\\\\\\\\\\`,String.raw`\\\//\\/\//\\///`,String.raw`\/\/\/`].map(s=>f([...s]).join`\n`).join`\n\n`
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f([...i.value]).join`\n`
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 65 bytes

```
INPUT S$WHILE""<S$C$=SHIFT(S$)DEC N,@L>C$?" "*N;C$INC N,@H<C$WEND
```

Answer (score 0):

## [**K4**](http://kx.com/download/), 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
-1(-1+\a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x)$$x:
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)-1(-1+\a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x)$$x:"\\\\\\//\\\\/\\//\\\\///"
\
 \
  \
  /
 /
 \
  \
  /
  \
  /
 /
 \
  \
  /
 /
/
```

Works if you start with a `/` too:

```
q)k)-1(-1+\a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x)$$x:"/\\\\/\\\\/"
/
\
 \
 /
 \
  \
  /
```

**Explanation:**

Generate list of negative numbers to (left) pad each of the input characters. Struggled to get a formula that worked, will look at the other solutions to see if there is a more simple method:

```
q)k)"/"=x
0001100101100111b
q)k)-1 1"/"=x
-1 -1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 1
q)k)~~':a:-1 1"/"=x
1001010111010100b
q)k)a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x
-1 0 0 1 0 -1 0 1 -1 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0
q)k)a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x
0 -1 -1 0 1 0 -1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 1 1
q)k)+\a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x
0 -1 -2 -2 -1 -1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -1 -1 -2 -2 -1 0
q)k)-1+\a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x
-1 -2 -3 -3 -2 -2 -3 -3 -3 -3 -2 -2 -3 -3 -2 -1
```

Full breakdown:

```
-1(-1+\a-a*~~':a:-1 1"/"=x)$$x: / the solution
                             x: / save input as variable x
                            $   / string (converts to char lists))
                           $    / pad
  (                       )     / do this together
                     "/"=x      / boolean list of x equal to /
                 -1 1           / index into this list
               a:               / save as variable a
           ~~':                 / differ (not-not-each-previous)
         a*                     / multiply by a
       a-                       / subtract from a
     +\                         / sums
   -1                           / (start summing from -1)
-1                              / print to stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-R`, 13 bytes

```
¬®ùZ>'/?°V:V´
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=rK75Wj4nLz+wVjpWtA==&input=LVIKIlxcXC8vXFwvXC8vXFwvLy8i)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Uq mZ{ZùZ>'/?++V:V--

Input: U = string of / and \, V = 0 (default)

Uq                    Split into chars
   mZ{                Map...
        Z>'/?           If the char is rightward (backslash)...
             ++V          Pre-increment V
                :V--      Otherwise, post-decrement V
      Zù                Left-pad the char with spaces to length V

-R                    Join with newline before printing
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 28 bytes

```
FlaIlQ'\PsX++v.lE{PsXv.l--v}
```

With a post decrement operator, this could be way shorter.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fLSfRMydQPSagOEJbu0wvx7UayALSurpltf///4@JidHXB2IIqa8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>47</s> 42 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)

Inspired by [pxeger's Zsh answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226523/11261).

```ruby
->a{w=0
a.map{" "*(_1<?@?w-=1:~-w+=1)+_1}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXTtEqvLbQ24EvVyEwuqlRSUtDTiDW3sHezLdW0Nrep0y7VtDTW14w1ra6E61MszMnNSFdJTS4q5FBQKSkuKFdyiVeL1kjPycwuAZGJRcSxXal4KRPmClTExMfr6MfoxMRABAA)

Comment: [42](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3tXTtEqvLbQ24EvVyEwuqlRSUtDTiDW3sHezLdW0Nrep0y7VtDTW14w1ra6E61MszMnNSFdJTS4q5FBQKSkuKFdyiVeL1kjPycwuAZGJRcSxXal4KRPmClTExMfr6MfoxMRABAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
JCPDḌ€ḷṡ+ðṙ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kp9S7IKlpSVpuhbbvJwDXB7u6HnUtObhju0Pdy7UPrzh4c6ZS4qTkouhShbcVIxWiolR0oEQ-jAGnKevFAtRCQA)

##### Explanation

```
JCPDḌ€ḷṡ+ðṙ  # Implicit input
JC           # Charcodes of input
  PD         # Are prime, duplicate
    Ḍ€ḷ      # Double, complement
       ṡ+    # Add to cumsums
         ðṙ  # Right-justify
             # Implicit output
```